# Proper correlated sql query

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
Salary  Sum
10       10
20       30
10       40
70       110
```

I need a query which give me the datatable in above format,in this the values of sum column is depend on the salary column

Comment: Yes,you are perfectly right,Sorry at the time of posting the question i didn't know the term running total

Comment: No problem. I don't have a good answer for you though: it's complicated. I would consider calculating it in whatever other language you're working with. Otherwise, here's some reading for you :) http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/28/calculating-running-totals-in-sql-server-2005---the-optimal.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a primary key in you table you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Salary INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    (1,10),
    (2,20),
    (3,10),
    (4,70)

SELECT
    tbl.Salary,
    SUM(tbl2.Salary) AS [Sum]
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
    JOIN @tbl AS tbl2
        ON (tbl2.ID <= tbl.ID)
GROUP BY 
    tbl.ID,
    tbl.Salary
ORDER BY 
    tbl.ID,
    tbl.Salary
```